# Necesito ayuda, quiero hacer al crear un nuevo post este se muestre de primer lugar pero poseo un error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Buenos días actualmente poseo un error en mi pagina y no encuentro el motivo, quiero lograr que al crear un nuevo post este se encuentre de primer lugar que los anteriores por ser el mas nuevo, utilice:
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC";` pero me da el siguiente error

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería muchísimo.

CODE: db.php

```
<?php

session_start();
require('connect.php');

function dd($value)
{
    echo "<pre>", print_r($value, true), "</pre>";
    die();
}


function executeQuery($sql, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $values = array_values($data);
    $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}


function selectAll($table, $conditions = [])
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC";
    if (empty($conditions)) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;    
    } else {
        // $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username='ElVictox' AND admin=1";
        
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $values = array_values($conditions);
        $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
        $stmt->bind_param($types, $values);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;
    }
}



function selectOne($table, $conditions)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC";
    
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    
        $sql = $sql . " LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $conditions);
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        return $records;
    }

function create($table, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    $id = $stmt->insert_id;
    return $id;
    
}

function update($table, $id, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    
    $sql = $sql . " WHERE id=?";
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}


function delete($table, $id)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=?";
      
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, ['id' => $id]);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}
```

TABLE SQL:

[image]

ERROR:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your
> SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE title=? LIMIT 1' at
> line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\database\db.php:17 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\database\db.php(17): mysqli->prepare('SELECT *
> FROM p...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\database\db.php(78):
> executeQuery('SELECT * FROM p...', Array) #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\helpers\validatePost.php(12): selectOne('posts',
> Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\controllers\capitulos.php(18):
> validatePost(Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\capitulos\create.php(1):
> include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #5 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\database\db.php on line 17

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el error está en que añades el WHERE después del ORDER BY. El ORDER BY debería ir al final de la consulta SQL.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE condition = value ORDER BY id DESC
```

Podrías solucionarlo en la función de *selectOne* y *selectAll* haciendo algo parecido, modificando el código de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
$i = 0;
foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
    if ($i === 0){
        $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
            
    } else {
       $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
    }
    $i++;
}
$sql = $sql . " ORDER BY id DESC";
$sql = $sql . " LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Disculpas pero no entendi muy bien lo que tengo que hacer, cambie a | SELECT * FROM $table WHERE condition = value ORDER BY id DESC | pero me sigue dando el mismo error, o donde tiene que ir la consulta SQL?

Comment: Por lo que veo te da el error en la función de selectOne que es donde tienes el LIMIT 1. Igualmente quizá deberías cambiarlo también en la de selectAll. He editado la respuesta para que vieras la diferencia.

Comment: Gracias el error fue solucionado pero ahora las nuevas publicaciones no se muestran de primer lugar porque ocurrirá eso?

Comment: ¿Puede que haya alguna condición que haga que no se muestre esa publicación?

Comment: Las publicaciones se muestran correctamente, lo que me gustaría es que al agregar nuevas estas se muestren de primer lugar en la web, cuando dejo todo junto: | $sql = "INSERT INTO $table SET ORDER BY id DESC "; | funciona se muestra la ultima publicación de primer lugar, pero al crear una nueva me da el error. Ahora hice el cambio que me dijiste, no me da el error pero las publicaciones nuevas ya no se muestran de primer lugar.